# ¿Esta bien implementada la red que hice?

Tags: redes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]En Bogotá hay una sede principal donde se encuentran los servidores principales y de
respaldo. Para la interconexión de las sedes se desea contratar fibra-óptica, buscando que todas
las sedes tengan un acceso rápido y confiable a los servidores de la sede principal. Localmente en
cada sede, se planea tener una conexión de alta velocidad para cada equipo de cómputo.
Las Ciudades donde hay cobertura se determinan a continuación:
BOGOTÁ:
Número de Sedes: 3
Número de equipos: 420
Descripción: Son sedes ubicadas en distritos lejanos para mejor cobertura y cada sede cuenta con
edificios superiores a 2000 mts2 de área, con cableado estructurado. En la Sede Principal hay 210
equipos, en la sede B hay 90 y en la sede C 120 equipos.
MEDELLÍN:
Número de Sedes: 2
Número de Equipos: 250
Descripción: Dos sedes pequeñas idénticas con un área de 1200 mts2, cada una con 125 equipos.
MANIZALES:
Número de Sedes: 1
Número de Equipos: 50
PEREIRA:
Número de Sedes: 1
Número de Equipos: 120

De lo anterior, lo implemente en cisco packet tracert , estaba pensando en implementarlo como se muestra en la imagen, pero no se si este bien la conexión entre las 4 ciudades como se plantea en el enunciado.  , pero no se si se podrá o que mas le tengo que agregar ? para que quede bien implementada con base a la descripción?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huyCh.pngí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta seria la red que yo implememntaria en tu caso, debes ajustar la cantidad de sw de acceso dependiendo del número de usuarios y número de puertos por sw que tengas. Puse una granja de servidores en la sede principal de Bogota que es lo que en un inicio describias en tu duda.Espero haber ayudado en algo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada y solo a manera de comentario personal ¿Frame Relay? porque no le apuestas a tecnologías como MPLS que brindan muchas mas ventajas como QoS, mejor administración, perfecta armonia con casi todas las tecnologias previas, y seria un dolor de cabeza menos si vas a usar FO en la estructura lan. Si bien es algo mas costosa la inversión inicial vale la pena con el ahorro en administración que supone y las ventajas que tendras en la facilidad de nuevas implemtaciones futuras. Ahora con respecto a la infraestructura en la entrada de red (internet) de cada ciudad es recomendable instalar un firewall como medida de seguridad ya sea fisico o como software dentro del router ademas separa tu granja de servidores de la red de datos ¨publica¨.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola gracias.. Pero me podrias decir como seria implementada la red del ejercicio en si, es que nunca he trabajado en cisco con multilayer, y server entonces no me queda del todo claro..Podrias decirme como lo implemento de manera sencillo y asi con base al ejemplo de las ciudades y yo lo desarroollo en cisco packet? Porfavor muchas gracias